# Div horizontal scroll issues when the width of the div is increased

Tags: html, css

I have 2 internal div's within a main div

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uwdnH/

Illustration - http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/8485/tablek.png

### HTML

```
<div class="mytable">
    <div class="leftNavTable">
        <a herf="#">div1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightNavTable">
        <a herf="#">div2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.mytable {
float:left;
width:300px;
height:200px;
border-width:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#000;
overflow:scroll;
}

.leftNavTable{
float:left;
width:75px;
height:250px;
border-width:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#FF0000;
}

.rightNavTable {
float:left;
width:200px;
height:250px;
border-width:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:rgb(0,0,255);

}
```

My requirement is that..

1)I wanted the size of div2 to be more but if I increase the width div2 will come below div1

2)Also there should be horizontal scrollbar only to div2

3)Vertical scrolling of div2 should make div1 also to scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To increase the width of div2, you will also need to increase the width of the outer mytable, or decrease div1.

2) to put a horizontal scrollbar on div2, apply `overflow-x:auto` to it.

3) You're doing that the right way now, by having the outer div scroll. However, if you don't want the outer div to have a horizontal scrollbar, use `overflow-y` instead of `overflow`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions Mr Lister, but now if i want to horizontally scroll div2 i'll have to scroll down till the end and only then i can use the scrollbars .. updated - http://jsfiddle.net/uwdnH/1/

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to do it with CSS alone. But with a bit of Javascript, http://jsfiddle.net/uwdnH/4/ should be roughly what you want. The left div is still a bit problematic though: since all of it moves with the right div, you'll see its border scrolling with its content. But I hope you can work with this...

Comment: OK. By the way, I did manage to keep the border of the left column fixed, but at the cost of introducing another div. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwdnH/5/). This is more like you want it, I presume.

Comment: the first was the like the more i wanted .. jsfiddle.net/uwdnH/4 thank you for your valuable time on this :) cheers!